# nginx duplicate default server error

Tags: nginx

I get the following error in nginx

```
: a duplicate default server for 0.0.0.0:80 in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:2
```

My file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default is:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Comment: have you copy this file as a "template" for another domain?

Answer (score 1):

Remove this "default_server" on line 1 of the server config.

Answer (score 0):

Run `grep default_server /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` and remove the duplicate from the other file(s)

Answer (score 0):

Run `grep -R default_server /etc/nginx` to see where `default_server` is defined and remove the duplicates. Only one site per port can be defined.

Answer (score -1):

you got this error because of inside `sites-enabled` directory multiple files  remove the by

1. get the directory by `cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` show the list of items in the directory by `ls`
2. `rm *******` use this command remove multiple files.
3. and run this code for checking the nginx working or not`sudo nginx -t`